# Please vet : Special case from proof of $\gcd(a,b) \mid a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I have worked out a case based on negative values, for checking my understanding of the subject. Please vet it.

Have stated the proof to show the variables used, so as to link to the actual example. 
Proof: In the derivation of the proof (by contradiction) that (given, $\gcd =c$) $c \mid a$, the division algorithm is considered.
 $\exists t,u \in \mathbb{Z}, s.t.: a = ct + u, 0 \le u \lt c.$

Hence, $a = ct +u = axt + byt +u$
=> $u = a(1-xt) + b(-yt)$.
 As $c$ is smallest positive linear combination <del>hence c $\le$ a, b</del>. 

 By definition, $u \lt c$, & a linear combination of $a,b$. 
As, $c$ is the smallest such combination; so: $u = 0$.

==> Question: It seems that $|c| \le |a|,|b|$. So, is it the positive value of $a,b$ that needs be taken for comparison with $c$. Also, by defn., $c = \gcd$, so $c$ must be positive.

---

The special case here is based on negative values of either $a$ or $b$. 
 It is given: $u = a(1-xt) + b(-yt)$,
 Now, to numerically state that : $u$ is smaller than $c$, need state :
 $$a(1-xt) + b(-yt) \lt ax + by$$
=> $a \lt ax(1+t) + by(1+t)$.

1. Let,  $a = -3, b= -5; c = 1; x = -2, y = 1$
 Finding the value of t, by substituting values in the above inequality:
$-3 \lt -3\cdot-2(1+t) -5\cdot1\cdot(1+t)$
$-3 \lt (1+t)$
$t \gt -4$

Taking the smallest value of $t= -3$
=> $u = a(1-xt) + b(-yt)$ 
=> $u = -3(1+3x) -5(3y)$
=> $u = 15 -15 = 0$

 Any higher value of $t$ leads to a negative value of $u$, but as $u$ cannot be less than $0$, so only one value of $t$ is acceptable.


2. Let,  $a = -3, b= 5; c = 1; x = -2, y = -1$
 Finding the value of t, by substituting values in the above inequality:
$-3 \lt -3\cdot-2(1+t) -5\cdot(1+t)$
$-3 \lt (1+t)$
$t \gt -4$

Taking the smallest value of $t= -3$
=> $u = a(1-xt) + b(-yt)$ 
=> $u = -3(1+3x) + 5(3y)$
=> $u = -3(1-6) + 5(-3)$
=> $u = 0$

 Any higher value of $t$ leads to a negative value of $u$, but as $u$ cannot be less than $0$, so only one value of $t$ is acceptable.

3. Considering now positive values of $a,b$, with $a = 3, b= 5, c = 1, x = 2, y = -1$
Finding the value of t, by substituting values in the above inequality:
$3 \lt +3\cdot2(1+t) -5\cdot(1+t)$
$3 \lt (1+t)$
$2 \lt t$
$t \gt 2$

Taking the smallest value of $t= 3$
=> $u = a(1-xt) + b(-yt)$ 
=> $u = 3(1-6) + 5(3)$
=> $u = 0$

 Any higher value of $t$ leads to a negative value of $u$, but as $u$ cannot be less than $0$, so only one value of $t$ is acceptable.

---

As euclidean division is used, hence a unique value of quotient and remainder is there, and this gels with only one value of $t$ in each case.

Comment: Please down-vote (and close) it (without any reason), as it is a ritual now with me. Please follow the ritual. Anyway, what difference it makes to me. No up-votes, and any addition is by accepting answers to my questions. And can read from 'deleted posts'.

Comment: Please answer my question regarding comparing only modulus of $a,b$ with $c$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I think that the part "hence $c\le a,b$" can be (has to be) removed. I mean, it should be enough to say "We have $u=a(1-tx)+b(-ty)$ which means that $u$ is linear combination of $a,b$. Since $0\le u\lt c$, and $c$ is the smallest positive linear combination of $a,b$, we have to have $u=0$."

Comment: Re-read  before submitting, posting, or publishing, Consider it to be a story. Characters  must be "introduced" to the readers. You did not "introduce" the character "$c$". In other words, find the first mention of a "character" and check that you defined it

Comment: @mathlove I have made the correction. Such details are good to point at. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I thought it would be implicit, so omitted that. Anyway, edited it. Will take care in future.